# Format date in JS using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

There is the following code:

```
console.log(order.start_time);
console.log(moment(order.start_time).format("HH:MM"));
```

I just want to get hour and minute from date using moment and display it. Output:

```
2014-06-30T09:00:00.000Z
13:06
```

But I don't understand why my date is formatted incorrectly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc here:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

You should use HH:mm. Then your time will have right format.

Further information, the time might be incorrectly as you expected because timezone. Momentjs auto display time in your system timezone.

Update:
To display time in specified Timezone, use "zone" method:

```
console.log(moment(order.start_time).zone('+00').format("HH:mm"));
```

Comment: How can I display time without my timezone?

Comment: Simple: console.log(moment(order.start_time).zone('+00').format("HH:mm"));

Answer (score 4):

Please note that there is a difference between `MM` and `mm`. The first formatting option is used for **months**, while the second is for `days`.

More information here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Keyword: timezones. When you parse date without `Z` you will have exact time.

Comment: How can I fix that time will be the same?